# HBase Get values where rowkey in

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql

How do I get all the values in HBase given Rowkey values?

```
val tableName = "myTable"
val hConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
val hTable = new HTable(hConf, tableName)
val theget= new Get(Bytes.toBytes("1001-A")) // rowkey values (1001-A, 1002-A, 2010-A, ...)
val result = hTable.get(theget)
val values = result.listCells()
```

The code above only works for one rowkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Batch operations. Please refer the link below for Javadoc : [Batch Operations on HTable](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#batch(java.util.List,%20java.lang.Object[]))

Another approach is to Scan with a start row key & end row key (First & Last row keys from an sorted ascending set of keys). This makes more sense if there are too many values.

Answer (score 0):

There is `htable.get` method that take list of Gets:

```
List<Get> gets = ....
List<Result> results = htable.get(gets)
```